# How to use find command and filter error messages

Tags: find, stdout

I'm running this command : **find / | grep corectrl | grep log**

And I get a lot of permission denied errors and I would like to send stderr to null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can redirect STDERR by appending `2>/dev/null` to the `find` command (read  `man bash`), thusly:

```
find / 2>/dev/null | ...
```

BUT, the rest of your command is suboptimal. Read `man find`,

```
find / -type f -name 'corectl.log' -print
```

Or, if the file was created yesterday or earlier, read `man locate`,

```
locate corectl.log
```